# How to display an MKAnnotation above an MKOverlay in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkoverlay

I have an MKMapView that has both MKAnnotations and an MKOverlay. I have a custom MKAnnotationView which is drawing fine, as well as the MKOverlay. The problem is the overlay is drawing on top of the annotations. (I know, I know, it is called an "OVERlay" for a reason!)

I'd like to display the annotations on TOP of the overlay. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are calling addOverlays: and addAnnotations: the annotations should display above the overlays. Check out the KMLViewer sample app which loads in a KML file and populates the map with multiple polygon overlays and pin annotations. I even modified it to match your scenario and replaced the pins with a custom annotation image and it still worked fine.

Comment: Does the order in which you call addOverlays and addAnnotations matter?

Comment: No it doesn't - it will add annotations on top of overlays regardless of when each is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was code I inherited and found they were overriding the addOverlays and instead adding as a subview. Hooray!

Comment: Ah yes that'll do it. Glad you figured it out!